# How can i get topicassignments associated with collaborationgroupfeed?

Tags: chatter-api

Iam trying to get TopicAssignment records that are associated to CollaborationGroupFeed. I tried following but didn't work. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems sad, but I think it is impossible today.
There was a link to FeedItem from Collaborationgroupfeed in the past, but it got removed, and only works for API 22.0 or older

```
select id from topicassignment where entityid in (select feedpostid from collaborationgroupfeed)
```

[see here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupfeed.htm)

salesforce cheatsheet shows FeedItem as a parent of Collaborationgroupfeed, but that does not work either.

As there us no connection between Collaborationgroupfeed and FeedItem I think there is no way to connect TopicAssigments. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but there are methods that return the 5 most recently used topics for specific Chatter groups: [REST doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_groups_GroupTopics.htm), [Apex doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_Topics_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_Topics_getRecentlyTalkingAboutTopicsForGroup).

The error you got from the SOQL query is happening because TopicAssignment.EntityId is a reference, while CollaborationGroupFeed.Id is an ID. I'm not sure how to get around that either.